# Correctly delimit single quotes in postgres insert/update

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to delimit any single quotes in a text field in a postgreSQL UPDATE statement. If I consider the following, replacing `'` with `''` as seems to be needed it still doesn't function as I expect. Also, what do you do if someone sends `'''` in the string for example?

```
var userid = request.decoded.id;
var incomingString = "Hello I'm a user.";
var newBio = incomingString.replace("'", "''");

pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function(err, client, done){
                   client.query("UPDATE users SET bio = "+newBio+" WHERE user_id = "+userid+"", function(err, result){
                                done();
                                if(err){
                                response.json({message:"err in db input."});
                                }
                                else{
                                response.json({message:"success"});
                                }
                                });
                   });
```

Should I simply change the above SQL statment to something like the below? Does that solve the SQL injection vulnerability and need to escape single quotes?

```
"UPDATE users SET bio = $1 WHERE user_id = $2", [newBio, userid]",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not escape SQL special characters manually.

Your second example is right. Using prepared/parametrized statements eliminates SQL injection threat.